# String ou dados binários seriam truncados

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Ocorre esse erro quando tento executar minha procedure, não sei o porque acontece isso.

meu codigo:

```
    Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection()
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
        Try
            con.ConnectionString = "Server = 10.230.11.43;Database=GFT_CAD;User Id=sa;Password = qweasd;"

            con.Open()
            cmd.Connection = con
            cmd = New SqlCommand("prdInserirDocDB", con)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure


 cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@SITUACAO_CACS", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = SITUACAO_CACS
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@CGC_CPF_PORTADOR", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = CGC_CPF_PORTADOR
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@FONE_CEL_PORT", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = FONE_CEL_PORT

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("inserido com sucesso")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("erro em: " & ex.Message)
```

Minha prodecure:

```
@VR_ULT_PAGTO  DECIMAL(09,2) ,
@VR_PRINCIPAL  DECIMAL(09,2) ,
@SITUACAO_CACS  VARCHAR(03) ,
@CGC_CPF_PORTADOR VARCHAR(15),
@FONE_CEL_PORT VARCHAR(17) 

as 
Begin

insert into tCImp_Doc(
SDO_ATUAL,
SDO_PARC_PEND,
SDO_LEGADO,
DT_ULT_PAGTO,
VR_ULT_PAGTO,
SITUACAO_CACS,
CGC_CPF_PORTADOR,
FONE_CEL_PORT 
 )
 values(
@SDO_PARC_PEND,
@SDO_LEGADO,
@DT_ULT_PAGTO,
@VR_ULT_PAGTO,
@SITUACAO_CACS,
@CGC_CPF_PORTADOR,
@FONE_CEL_PORT

 )
 end
```

Ignorem os campos errados meu código tem muitos campos não quis colocar todos.

Answer (score 5):

Esse erro ocorre quando você tentar inserir em um campo um valor maior do que foi definido a ele no momento de sua criação.

Por exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE TESTE ( 
   id int,
   descr varchar(5))
```

Se eu tentar inserir **6** caracteres ou mais em um campo definido para aceitar apenas **5**.

```
INSERT INTO TESTE( 1, '123456' )
```

Eu recebo esse erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui usei um campo varchar, mas o mesmo vale para qualquer tipo de campo. Por isso que  a mensagem é genérica e fala em **String or Binary data**.